# Rendering one mesh before another in Unity 2018?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of models with inverted normals for outlines. However, I want to render the meshes in front of the outlines so there's no glitchy clipping. Does anyone know of a shader or way to render the meshes in front of the outlines?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ1Qq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the render queue for the outline shader should fix your issues.

In the outline shader:

```
 Tags{ "Queue" = "Geometry-1"}
```

Just make sure the queue number to render the outline is before the other objects. Example of tags location below.

[image: Example Shader]

Comment: Where do I change the tags? Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: @DavilosCoyote I added an image of an example shader for you